# Which 3-manifolds can be cubulated?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

I am trying to get a picture of what is currently known about cubulability of 3-manifolds, though cannot seem to find a good overview.  I am personally most interested in compact 3-manifolds with boundary embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but would be happy to hear any answers to this question.  If I had to name one concrete question, it would be:

**Question:** *Can you cubulate every compact 3-manifold $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$?  If not, which ones can you cubulate?  What are some specific examples of non-cubulable $M$?*

I am aware of some scattered results, e.g.,

- all hyperbolic 3-manifolds are cubulable (discussed in Sections 4.5, 4.6 of [this paper](https://www.uni-regensburg.de/Fakultaeten/nat_Fak_I/friedl/papers/3-manifold-groups-final-version-031115))
- there is some discussion about cubulability of Kähler groups/Kähler manifolds [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.08474.pdf)
- there is a characterization in terms of the boundary [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.3609.pdf)

Apart from the result about hyperbolic 3-manifolds, I find it quite hard to connect largely algebraic results like these back to a more concrete geometric/topological picture.

Comment: Graph manifolds which are cubulated have a characterization in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.1309) by Hagen and Przytycki

Comment: Note that the original meaning of "cubulated" was that there's a cubulation of the manifold in the proper sense (namely that there exists a locally CAT(0) cube complex that is homeomorphic to the manifold). The meaning in the Hagen-Przytycki is weaker: it means that the fundamental group acts properly cocompactly on a CAT(0) cube complex (which can be of much higher dimension). Saying that the manifold is cubulable to mean this is a bit misleading.

Comment: @YCor Thank you! That in itself is a very valuable clarification.